# Find/check disk usage/utilization for entire hard drive (all of its partitions) from command line

Tags: command-line, hard-disk, disk-usage

I have been looking for a command that would give me available space, used space, and percent of space utilization for an entire hard disk (drive). Unfortunately most of the answers I can find online deal with *partitions*, not *drives*.

(Not sure if relevant, but I use Ubuntu, and would need to use this command on both 14.04 and 18.04)

Here is the problem:

1) `df -h` gives only info on partitions, not entire drives - and includes in-memory filesystems like `tmpfs`, which I don't need:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           788M  2.2M  786M   1% /run
/dev/sdb6        59G   53G  3.3G  95% /
tmpfs           3.9G  183M  3.7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      112M  112M     0 100% /snap/dotnet-sdk/63
...
tmpfs           788M   20K  788M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           788M   64K  788M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       230G  217G  1.4G 100% /media/testpart1
/dev/sda2       230G  150G   69G  69% /media/testpart2
```

Just for fun, tried to explicitly specify `/dev/sda` for `df` - but that doesn't work:

```
$ df -h /dev/sda
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
```

... as it gives me the size of `udev` mount.

2) `du -hs /` works on directories - so it would also include USB drives or whatever else I may have mounted under `/media`

3) `lsblk` lists both disks and corresponding partitions, but lists only total available size/space, not used space nor percentage (also includes tmpfs and such, but that can be suppressed by targeting the device node for the disk in the arguments):

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 232.9G  0 part /media/testpart1
└─sda2   8:2    0 232.9G  0 part /media/testpart2
```

So, my question is - how can I find total available size/space, used size/space (in human-readable units, such as MB, GB etc), and usage/utilization percentage for a single hard disk drive (which includes usage of all of its partitions) with a single Linux command line - without interference from tmpfs or other mounted system (like USB thumbdrives)?

Comment: The GNU Coreutils implementation of `df` has lots of options - have you tried something like `df -h --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs} --total` (assuming your shell supports brace expansion)?

Comment: @guest: `lsblk -fs` gives me partition info, not disk info, and no sizes whatsoever are posted; `lsblk -o name,fssize,fsavail,fsused,fsuse% /dev/sda` gives me: "lsblk: unknown column: fssize,fsavail,fsused,fsuse%" ; `lsblk -O /dev/sda | less -S` works, but there are no fsavail columns or anything - only SIZE is listed (which is available size); I have `lsblk from util-linux 2.31.1` if it matters.

Comment: @steeldriver: `df -h --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs} --total` works, but on one of my systems, it also mixes in `/dev/sdb` along `/dev/sda`, so it doesn't help much.